# Adding local images to WebView doesn't respect EXIF rotation

Tags: android, android-webview, android-camera

I add several images to a `WebView` and images are rotated **90 degrees** from what's expected.
This is because the **Samsung camera** shoots with .jpg photos + EXIF rotation tag.
Same images appear fine in the gallery but not in my `WebView`.

```java
String htmlWithImages = "<html> <some html>";
htmlWithImages += imageUri; // Image's content uri like content://
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlWithImages, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Is this a bug in `WebView`? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use css3 to rotate the images inside the WebView: http://bavotasan.com/2011/rotated-images-with-css3/ or http://www.kavoir.com/2009/08/css-rotate-text-image-elements-by-90-180-or-270-degrees.html

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Comment: That's a good workaround and it works OS 3.0+. A universal workaround would help.

Comment: CSS3 rotations has one big problem. When it rotates, it takes old width and height of the image. I'm already using CSS to stretch image to take 95% of the width, now when it rotates, the dimensions are old.

Comment: but this will rotate all images from webview. Is there any solution if I want to rotate only some of images from webview